# Router seems to deny access to particular site

Tags: router

It seems that I can access any site on the internet (including serverfault) through my router, but for some reason bitbucket.org does not work (when I go to the URL in Chrome, it takes a long time then times out with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT - if I use SourceTree, it also takes a long time then times out).  If I take my laptop elsewhere and connect through another wifi network, I can get to bitbucket.org just fine.

I'm using a Macbook, connecting to my Huawei B593s-601 router via wifi.  I've systematically checked through every setting I can reach in the router's console, I've especially made sure that it doesn't have any URLs in the blacklist (it doesn't).

In the firewall section, the Firewall Level is set to "Low (disabled)", underneath this setting it says:

```
 Stateful Packet Inspection (SPI) is enabled. Inbound (from Internet to
 LAN) policy: Dropped
         Remote authorized access will override the inbound policy. 
 Outbound (from LAN to Internet) policy: Accepted.
 Filtering strategy:Disabled
 MAC filtering:Disabled
 IP filtering:Disabled
 URL filtering:Disabled
 DoS attack: Enable
    Block Denial of Service (DoS) attacks from the LAN and Internet, such as 
    SYN floods and ping floods.
```

Comment: If you connect to a proxy or VPN, is the website still blocked, update your question with your results.

Comment: Any chance the router is using another DNS server? See http://superuser.com/questions/1108068/what-router-settings-would-prevent-me-from-accessing-css-files-via-https/1112161#1112161

Answer (score -1):

This may depend on your listed DNS options for network adapter.

THese should give same results in a command window

> ping 104.192.143.3
>
> ping bitbucket.org